# XML invalid tags

Tags: php, xml, opencart

what i should do to prevent invalid XML tags in the custom getaway's callback function?

```
$h = fopen("banks/Mybank/log.txt", 'a');
        fwrite($h, 'ConfirmRequest: '.print_r($_REQUEST['ConfirmRequest'],true)."\n");  
        fclose($h);
```

the output is:

```
ConfirmRequest: &lt;ConfirmRequest&gt;&lt;TransactionId&gt; Cool Attitude  #89&lt;/TransactionId&gt;&lt;PaymentId&gt;327600020200&lt;/PaymentId&gt;&lt;PaymentDate&gt;02.10.2013 23:41:26&lt;/PaymentDate&gt;&lt;Amount&gt;7000&lt;/Amount&gt;&lt;CardType&gt;VISA!472291******9871&lt;/CardType&gt;&lt;Status&gt;N&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Reason&gt;Declined by merchant&lt;/Reason&gt;&lt;/ConfirmRequest&gt;
```

the result is same on

```
$_REQUEST['ConfirmRequest'];
```

and

```
$this->resuest->request['ConfirmRequest'];
```

==========================

huge thanks to gloomy.penguin!   can you tell me please, what have i done wrong here?

```
if(
        !openssl_verify(
                       'ConfirmRequest='.$ConfirmRequest,
                        base64_decode($signature),
                        openssl_get_publickey($cert)
                       )
            ) 
            die("signature error");




  $parser = xml_parser_create('');
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
            xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
        xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $ConfirmRequest, $vals);
        xml_parser_free($parser); 


            foreach ($vals as $data)
                  {
                   if ($data['tag']=='STATUS')
                   $Status=$data['value'];
                   if ($data['tag']=='PAYMENTID')
                   $PaymentId=$data['value'];
                   if ($data['tag']=='PAYMENTDATE')
                   $PaymentDate=$data['value'];
                   if ($data['tag']=='TRANSACTIONID')
                   $TransactionId=$data['value'];
                   if ($data['tag']=='AMOUNT')
                   $Amount=$data['value'];
                   if ($data['tag']=='REASON')
                   $Reason=$data['value'];
               if ($data['tag']=='CARDTYPE')
                   $CardType=$data['value'];

                  }


            $sta = fopen("banks/MyBank/status.txt", 'a');
            fwrite($sta, .print_r($data)."\n"); 
            fclose($sta);
```

the output value is "1" ...

Comment: [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks gloomy.penguin!! can you help me please? i have edited my post

Comment: you should put `$sta = fopen(...` before the `foreach` and put `fwrite(...` inside the `foreach` and leave `fclose` where it is

Comment: the output is to many "1"

Comment: if openssl_verify logic doesn't works code below will by executed?

Comment: use this function instead of fwrite:  [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)... and yes.. if `openssl_verify` is false then the program will stop...

Comment: after using fputcsv the output file is empty

Comment: is there anything in `$data` or `$vals` going through the `foreach`?  and post your updated code. it should look something like... `$sta = fopen(...); foreach($vals as $data) { fputcsv($sta, $data, ','); } fclose($sta);`

Comment: or use `fwrite` but i'm not sure you want it saved as the format of `print_r`... but i don't know.  make sure whatever function is actually inside of the `foreach` and make sure that there is actual data in `$data`... do a `print_r($data)` to the screen when you write to the file just to see what it should be printing, i guess.  i am leaving.  good luck.  i am not sure if anyone else can help unless you update your post to include new code, exact output and the value of `$vals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer to your initial problem:  [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Since you have a new problem that is not related to your initial issue, I suggest closing this question (by choosing an answer to your question) and make a whole new post with your new problem.  Include the code you're using and what is in the variables so that people can help you out.

Comment: thanks for you attention.  can you see the code pls?? http://pastebin.com/MCEN8pA5